# Is there a way to derive parameters off of a VB 6.0 ADO Command Object?

Tags: vb6, ado

In .Net you can use SqlCommandBuilder to derive parameters, just wondering if there is anything similar to this in VB 6.0 using MS ADO 6.1 - Maybe i need a reference to a different library?

Spoiled, it seems very annoying to add every parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`<ADODB.Command>.Parameters.Refresh`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/174223) will populate the collection, obviously this requires an extra  round-trip so has an overhead.